# App crash reports not appearing after iOS7 update

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crash-dumps, memory-dump

OS: Windows 7 (Mac cannot be used)
Apple mobile devices running iOS7

We're testing our apps. In iOS6 and previous versions of iOS, we just needed to sync the iOS device using iTunes, and the app crash logs & memory dumps appeared in "C:\Users\ **USERNAME* \AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\ **DEVICENAME*" (mostly there was a ".crash" file). But after updating to iOS 7, the crash logs no longer appear in the specified directory when the iOS device is synced. Since crash logs are vital in knowing what caused the crash, we need them as soon as the app crashes. Please provide some help on how to get the crash logs.

EDIT: WHY ARE YOU GUYS DOWNVOTING?

Comment: Probably because this isn't a programming related question…?

Comment: This question is not for here as it's not related to programming. Otherwise use `iPhone Configuration Utility` http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1466

Comment: The downvoters are wrong.  Asking where to find crash logs is absolutely a programming-related question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Xcode organizer to see the crashes of your device and get it symbolicated.

Comment: Sync the device with iTunes. If it is not there, you need to connect it to a Mac with Xcode. Otherwise the user needs to open the settings app on the device, general, info, diagnose & usage, diagnose & usage data, select the crash entry, copy paste it and send it via email. Symbolication will be a mess though.

Comment: That's what i've been doing so far!

Comment: In some cases, we're asking beta-testers (who don't have XCode) to find and email crash-reports back to us.  So we need to tell them where to find the reports after they sync with iTunes.

Comment: There are alternatives for beta and app store release: multiple open source, free or commercial tools and services than specialise on collecting, symbolicating and grouping crash groups. Some go even further. There is no real need for all that manual work since years. (Disclaimer: I wrote QuincyKit.net and am part of HockeyApp.net)